# Angular Download Takes a long time to show download link

Tags: angular

I'm downloading large file to a client through a browser. When I initiate the download I can see the file transferring under developer tools once it is done transferring then I see the file transfer

[image]

To the user they do not see anything until the file finishes transferring then I finally see the file downloading
[image]

```
 downlodFile(id): void {

    let filedownloadInput = new FileDownloadInput();
    filedownloadInput.id = id;

    this._FileManagerService.downloadFile(filedownloadInput).subscribe(item => {
         this.InitializeDownload(item.fileName, item.fileToken).subscribe((data: any) => {

            this.blob = new Blob([data], { type: 'application/pdf' });

            var downloadURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(data);
            var link = document.createElement('a');
            link.href = downloadURL;
            link.download = item.fileName;
            link.click();

        });
    });
}
InitializeDownload(fileName:string, fileToken:string) {
    const url = AppConsts.remoteServiceBaseUrl + '/FileManager/GetFile';
    this.token = this._tokenService.getToken();
    let params = new HttpParams();

    params = params.append('fileName', fileName);
    params = params.append('fileToken', fileToken);
    const httpOptions = {
        responseType: 'blob' as 'json',
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
            "Authorization": "Bearer " + this.token
        }),
        params: params
    };

    return this._httpClient.get(url, httpOptions);
}
```

Comment: try using filesaver modulee

Comment: I tried by adding it in the subscribe and got the same result